# In Woocommerce foreach loop works but creates errors in log

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, woocommerce, product

I'm using the following code which creates a nice table, under the product summary on the single product page, however it is causing log errors which appears to be slowing the site down. Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

The errors are as follows:

> [22-May-2018 10:39:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /www1/84b/www.dizzydev9.co.uk/web/wp-content/themes/IHS/functions.php on line 750

The related code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', function() {

global $product;
$mols700ma_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_mol-s700ma');
$mols300ma_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_mol-s300ma');
$fluxtotal_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_total-radiometric-flux-mw');
$din5031300_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_din5031-10-360-780nm');
$din5031700_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_din5031-10-400-700nm');
$mccree300_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_adjusted-mccree-360-780nm');
$mccree700_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_adjusted-mccree-400-700');


echo '<table id="parametrics"><tr>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>240-790nm Total radiometric flux (mW)</span> 
</div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>PAR 400-700nm PPF µmol/s</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>PAR 360-780nm BPF µmol/s</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>PAR (adjusted DIN5031-10) 400-700nm BPF 
µmol/s</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>PAR (adjusted DIN5031-10) 360-780nm BPF 
µmol/s</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>PAR (adjusted McCree) 400-700nm BPF 
µmol/s</span></div></th>
<th class="rotate"><div><span>PAR (adjusted McCree) 360-780nm BPF 
µmol/s</span></div></th>
</tr>';
  echo '<tr><td>' ;
foreach ( $fluxtotal_values as $fluxtotal_value ) {
    echo $fluxtotal_value->name;
}
echo'</td><td>';    
foreach ( $mols700ma_values as $mols700ma_value ) {
    echo $mols700ma_value->name;
}
echo'</td><td>';
foreach ( $mols300ma_values as $mols300ma_value ) {
    echo $mols300ma_value->name;
}
echo'</td><td>';
foreach ( $din5031700_values as $din5031700_value ) {
    echo $din5031700_value->name;
}
echo'</td><td>';
foreach ( $din5031300_values as $din5031300_value ) {
    echo $din5031300_value->name;
}
echo'</td><td>';
foreach ( $mccree700_values as $mccree700_value ) {
    echo $mccree700_value->name;
}
echo'</td><td>';        
foreach ( $mccree300_values as $mccree300_value ) {
    echo $mccree300_value->name;
}
echo'</td></tr></table>';
}, 1);
```

Comment: So what is exactly on line 750?

Comment: So there is an error for each line with for each e.g.  
[23-May-2018 07:46:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /www1/84b/www.dizzydev9.co.uk/web/wp-content/themes/IHS/functions.php on line 672  
[23-May-2018 07:46:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /www1/84b/www.dizzydev9.co.uk/web/wp-content/themes/IHS/functions.php on line 676  
  
**line 672**       foreach ( $fluxtotal_values as $fluxtotal_value ) {  
**line 676**       foreach ( $mols700ma_values as $mols700ma_value ) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2021**

I finally found the source of your problem errors: You need to test that each array of terms is not empty before the foreach loop to avoid the error.

I have decided to revisit entirely your code, in a much compact way. Try that:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'product_attributes_custom_table', 1 );
function product_attributes_custom_table() {
    global $product;

    $product_attributes = array();
    
    // Set product attribute taxonomy and labels pairs in an array
    $keys_labels = array(
        'pa_total-radiometric-flux-mw'  => __('240-790nm Total radiometric flux (mW)'),
        'pa_mol-s700ma'                 => __('PAR 400-700nm PPF µmol/s'),
        'pa_mol-s300ma'                 => __('PAR 360-780nm BPF µmol/s'),
        'pa_din5031-10-400-700nm'       => __('PAR (adjusted DIN5031-10) 400-700nm BPF µmol/s'),
        'pa_din5031-10-360-780nm'       => __('PAR (adjusted DIN5031-10) 360-780nm BPF µmol/s'),
        'pa_adjusted-mccree-400-700'    => __('PAR (adjusted McCree) 400-700nm BPF µmol/s'),
        'pa_adjusted-mccree-360-780nm'  => __('PAR (adjusted McCree) 360-780nm BPF µmol/s'),
    );

    // Loop through the array
    foreach( $keys_labels as $key => $label ){
        if( taxonomy_exists($key) ){
            $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), $key );
            if( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                // Change $terms in a coma separated list of term names
                $term_names = join(', ', wp_list_pluck($terms, 'name'));
                // Set label and the coresponding term names in the array
                $product_attributes[$label] = $term_names;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( ! empty( $product_attributes ) ) {
        echo '<table id="parametrics"><tr>';
        
        // First loop for the labels
        foreach($product_attributes as $label => $term_names ){
            echo '<th class="rotate"><div><span>'.$label.'</span></div></th>';
        }
    
        echo '</tr><tr>';
        
        // Second loop for the term names
        foreach($product_attributes as $label => $term_names ){
            echo '<td>'.$term_names.'</td>';
        }
    
        echo'</td></tr></table>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for this unfortunately this is still creating the error

Comment: Hello, this is great thank you. It also only shows columns if they have data, so much better solution.

Comment: This has worked wonderfully until the latest version of Wordpress. I now get an error message if there is nothing to return. I've tried adding an if else statement that works for a simple function, but I seem to stop it showing anything it I apply the same method here. How do I apply if empty to this?

Comment: I'm so sorry I did mean to accept this at the time.